# How do I change the font size using MSDN?

Tags: c++, fonts, size, msdn

```
VOID BackgroundObject::DrawOverlay(WCHAR *wChar, UINT length)
{
  D2D1_SIZE_F renderTargetSize = m_pRenderTarget->GetSize();
  m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(Matrix3x2F::Identity());
  m_pRenderTarget->DrawText(wChar,
                          length - 1,
                          m_pD2DDriver->GetTextFormat(),
                          RectF(g_metrics.UnscaleX(10), 0, renderTargetSize.width,  renderTargetSize.height),
                          m_pD2DDriver->GetBrush(DrawingColor::White));
}
```

The code above is drawing the font onto a window, but I would like to change the size of the font.
How would I do this?

I'm very new to MSDN, anyways... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Showing my naive side, I always thought MSDN was the documentation resource library cut/pasted... errr.. i mean *studied* by Windows developers for the last 20 years. Perhaps you mean Windows API and DirectX?

Comment: What type is `m_pRenderTarget`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, There's a good chance it's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371766(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756692(v=vs.85).aspx)